# Invalid object name 'information_schema.columns' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

The following query used to work:

```
select * from information_schema.columns where column_name like ...
```

But now it's throwing an error:

```
Server: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'information_schema.columns'.
```

The application was upgraded but the view still has to exist in the database.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Either:

1. The database has a case-sensitive collation (try all upper case `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`)
2. Or you don't have permission.